# Accessing redirect URL via Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, redirect, selenium

Here's my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb009a1b2b4601317355f&redirect_uri=http://pythondev.insta.com/instagramredirect.html&response_type=code")
print driver.current_url
```

Even though the browser then redirects to a different URL after loading the URL with `driver.get()` when I do `print driver.current_url` of course, the URL that's printed is the original URL and not the redirect. Is there a way to get Selenium to "see" the actual current URL in the browser it opened?

Comment: have you looked at the URL that you are using? it has the redirect in it?

Comment: @TehTris The current URL redirects to another URL with the access code string at the end of the URL. That code is what I'd like to grab in an automated fashion (rather than copying from browser each time)

Comment: is something like `redirect_uri = driver.current_url.split('redirect_uri%3D')[-1]` what you are looking for? this puts "http%3A//pythondev.insta.com/instagramredirect.html%26response_type%3Dcode" into a string `redirect_uri`

Comment: I need the redirect URL `that https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb009a1b2b4601317355f&redirect_uri=http://pythondev.insta.com/instagramredirect.html&response_type=code` creates. It shows up immediatley after you paste  `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb009a1b2b4601317355f&redirect_uri=http://pythondev.insta.com/instagramredirect.html&response_type=code` into your browser.